# CTI Integration with sip / viop

Tags: apex, visualforce, cti, call-center

hi i want to make inbound and outbound call using a softphone on Salesforce. client provided me sip account which includes domain name,username, password (don’t have any api key). We have integrated a webphone api (webphone_api.js) to communicate between Salesforce and sip server as cti tool kit need api key and api to hit the server and make calls. Client want to use cti tool kit with sip account credentials.

Comment: I need your help, I just want to know whether it is possible or not with SIP/CTI/Salesforce? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add settings to your softphone's Call Center definition for the credentials?

Alternatively can your softphone prompt for credentials and store them in HTML5 local storage?